# How to read audio file in docker

Tags: docker, file, audio, speech-recognition, wav

I try to do SpeechRecognition in Python using docker. First of all I need to read a wav file, which I give as an argument with docker run. Below my code to read it:

import librosa

audio, rate = librosa.load("/app/new_file.wav", sr = 16000)

This works in Python, but doesn't work in Docker. I get error:
RuntimeError: Error opening 'new_file.wav': Format not recognised.
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'new_file.wav'

Can anybody has an idea whats going on? What should I do? I installed librosa library in requirements. My image: python:3.8-slim

Thanks for help.

Comment: How does that file get into the container?  If something is unexpectedly a directly, one possible cause is trying to bind-mount a file that doesn't exist, in which case Docker will create a directory instead on both the host and the container.

Comment: You are absoluttely right, thanks! I used "docker run -v new_file.wav:/app/new_file.wav image_name" instead of full path to the file. I didn't get any error so I thought docker can read it (Dockerfile is in the same folder). Now, thanks to your answer, I know that docker created a directory. It works when I gave full path to the file, thanks again!